# Positive definite matrix property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, positive-definite, positive-matrices

Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and let $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix. Define

$a^*=Q^T\operatorname{diag} \{ \lambda/2,...,\lambda/2,2\lambda^{-1},...2\lambda^{-1}\} Q$.

Show that

$\frac{1}{2}\lambda I \leq a^* \leq 2\lambda^{-1}I$

Comment: Well, go ahead! More seriously: What did you try and where did you get stuck? What definition of positive definite do you know?

Comment: If i can! :) I tried to make calculation with "my hand" but nothing arise ( in my head ). Then i tried to use some properties of positive define matrix, as if $A$ is positive define then $Q^T A Q$ is positive define, but again nothing. My definition of positive define is: $A$ is positive define iif $x^T A x > 0 $ for all $x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me handlet one side for you and you should try it for another side

\begin{align}a^*-\frac12\lambda I  &= Q^Tdiag(\frac{\lambda}{2}, \ldots,\frac{\lambda}{2}, \frac2\lambda , \ldots, \frac2\lambda  )Q -\frac{\lambda}{2}I\\
&=Q^Tdiag(\frac{\lambda}{2}, \ldots,\frac{\lambda}{2}, \frac2\lambda , \ldots, \frac2\lambda  )Q -Q^Tdiag(\frac{\lambda}{2}, \ldots,\frac{\lambda}{2}, \frac\lambda2 , \ldots, \frac\lambda2  )Q\\
&=Q^Tdiag(0, \ldots, 0, \frac2\lambda - \frac\lambda2, \ldots, \frac2\lambda-\frac\lambda2)Q\end{align}

Now, check that $\frac2\lambda - \frac\lambda 2 > 0$.

You might like to let $y=Qx$ and we have

$$x^T(a^*-\frac\lambda 2 I)x=y^Tdiag(0, \ldots, 0, \frac2\lambda - \frac\lambda 2, \ldots, \frac2\lambda-\frac\lambda2)y \ge 0$$

Comment: thanks a lot! Only one question: how can you switch from the first to the second line? I mean, it is a known property that $\lambda I = Q^T \lambda I Q$?

Comment: We have $Q^TQ=I$ since $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Ok, thank you. :)